# How can I ensure that my website that requires login can be accessed by Search Engine crawlers etc?

Tags: html, joomla, seo, web-crawler, joomla2.5

I have a Joomla 2.5 website which requires users to login to access.
Is it possible to allow google to crawl the website etc?

If an extension will allow this I can buy it.

Answer (score 0):

you can depend on HTTP headers (and look for google bots) but it is possible security flaw.

you should consider guest type account instead.

Answer (score 0):

You must show the same to Googlebot as you do to regular browsers. Showing google logged in content would be against guidelines, though you can look into [first click free](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/first-click-free-for-web-search.html)